# Is it feasible to host Magento on a windows platform for live sites?

Tags: hosting, windows

I have Magento running locally on Windows for development and I notice it's very much slower than my Virtual Box version running Linux.

I understand there are a lot of factors involved here i.e Resources available, programs running, background tasks etc and it's true that my virtual box has dedicated resources which are only used by Magento whereas I have lots more going on in Windows.

Does anyone host live Magento sites on Windows? Is it fast enough (will there be a difference assuming there is enough hardware)

Also, should I go with something like Xammp or would a direct installation of PHP on IIS work our faster?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

most likely not the answer you want, but here it is:

http://magento.com/resources/system-requirements

> Supported Operating Systems: Linux x86, x86-64
>
> Supported Web Servers: Apache 1.3.x Apache 2.0.x Apache 2.2.x Nginx
>   (starting from Magento 1.7 Community and 1.12 Enterprise versions)

In the 5+ years I have been using magento, I had never come across anyone who did host it on a windows platform for a live site.

Comment: I was assuming that would be the case and I am actually against the idea myself (why wrap something up which will make it slower). Thanks for the clarification though. A linux box it is.

Comment: I am having shivers just thinking about it ;)

Answer (score 7):

I have been running a live e-commerce site now on server 2008 for about 3 years now. (Running Magento 1.7)  I was told initially that this would be supported, and a piece of cake to run, however I have never run into this many issues, especially with speed, and support of third party extensions.  All of my .Net application run fine, and the web/db server both have more than adequate CPU/Ram/Network...etc.  When I upgrade Magento, I will be moving onto a Linux box.

Comment: Thanks for posting this, useful to have some real life experiences to hand.